# R - Use Optional Arguments in Nested Functions like 'kmeans'

Tags: r, list, k-means, optional-parameters, nested-function

I am trying to create a function that uses `dist` and `kmeans` from `tm` package.

My aim is to give the opportunity for having arguments as lists, in the main one, such way it could be used as arguments on above-mentioned functions.

There is an example:

```
tmpClust<-function(corpora, dist.args=list(method = "manhattan"), k, kmeans.args=list(algorithm="Lloyd"))
{
    dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpora)

    dm<-dist(dtm, dist.args)

    x<-kmeans(dm, k, kmeans.args)

    x$cluster
}
data(crude)
tmpClust(crude, k=3)
```

I get:

> Error in kmeans(dm, k, kmeans.args) : 'iter.max' must be positive
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In kmeans(dm, k, kmeans.args) : NAs introduced by coercion

And if I modify, on `tmpClust`, to `kmeans.args=list()`, I have:

> Error in if (is.na(iter.max) || iter.max < 1L) stop("'iter.max' must be positive") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

What I need to solve this?
I had tried use ellipsis but with no success.

Comment: Unfortunately, the R idiom is kind of convoluted, like `do.call(f, list(all_the_args))`

Comment: Could you make this into a reproducible example?

Comment: @Frank, I changed, in the function, to `x<-do.call(kmeans, list(dm, k, kmeans.args))`. And I obtain the same problems.

Comment: Your target should be a one-level list. `list(dm, k, kmeans.args)` is nested (with one list inside another), so instead you want `c(list(dm, k), kmeans.args)` or something similar.

Comment: @Frank: I think you mean `c(dm, k, kmeans.args)`, but that's otherwise the right answer:

Comment: @JWLM That makes a good answer, I think, though the example function you chose (in your deleted answer) is probably confusing.